# Jersey with Tomcat HTTP Status 500 - ClassFormatError

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to create REST service using Jersey. Deployment is successful, but when I'm trying to access on API url, I got error code 500. I'm working around it for 2 days, but have no luck. Please, help me.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error</location>
    </error-page>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>java-ee</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-java-ee</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javaee/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-web-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax/javaee-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JERSEY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My log:

```
02-Jul-2016 03:34:55.553 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-74] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/internet/ParseException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2248)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:808)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1249)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1114)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:124)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:283)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1338)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1419)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

02-Jul-2016 03:34:55.553 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-74] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet Jersey Web Application
 java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/mail/internet/ParseException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2248)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:808)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1249)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1114)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getAllDeclaredMethods(MethodList.java:70)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getPostConstructMethods(ComponentConstructor.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.<init>(ComponentConstructor.java:124)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:283)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1338)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1419)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try set the dependency scope to provided for the Java EE api deps, they should be given by the container

Comment: @gerrytan, I've just added https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail and it works now. It;s very strange, because I tried it earlier, but it didn't work...Whatever, thank you for comment.

Comment: All those Java EE dependencies should **definitely** be marked as "provided" because they come from the server you're running in; they shouldn't be included in the app itself.